# Select Maximum Row Value Per Document Type Grouped By Entity

Tags: mysql, max

I have run into a little bit of a problem with selecting the maximum value for a particular column from my table.

Data is inserted into the table through the use of a form, and there are 3 different document types that can be uploaded, either together, or only one document type at a time.

I would like to display the "Newest" documents per document type on screen, but am not sure how to achieve this. The newest document is determined by the mod_date only, which in this scenario would be the same as the upload date. For this column I actually use a TIMESTAMP field not only DATE.

TABLE Structure:

```
entity_number | doc_name | doc_type| mod_date   |
12348         | P_12348  | 1       | 2017-01-01 |
12348         | Z_12348  | 2       | 2017-01-02 | 
12348         | A_12348  | 1       | 2017-01-02 |    
11184         | P_11184  | 1       | 2017-01-02 | 
11184         | Z_11184  | 1       | 2017-01-02 |       
11184         | A_11184  | 1       | 2017-01-03 | 
11184         | G_11184  | 2       | 2017-01-03 | 
11184         | B_11184  | 3       | 2017-01-03 |
```

Initially I would like the following results to be displayed from my query:

```
entity_number | doc1_name | doc2_name | doc3_name |
12348         | A_12348   | Z_12348   |           |
11184         | A_11184   | G_11184   | B_11184   |
```

The query I have tried is the following, but for some reason I am only returning the first result.

```
SELECT 
    entity_number
,   MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 1 THEN doc_name END) doc1_name
,   MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN doc_name END) doc2_name
,   MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 3 THEN doc_name END) doc3_name
FROM
    scrm.mytable
GROUP BY
    entity_number;
```

Please let me know if you require more details.

Comment: What makes `a_12348` newer than `x_12348` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegelesen The only thing that indicates that it's newer would be the mod_date which would also be the upload date of the file.

Comment: This question is asked endlessly. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too, so have a look through Related questions

Comment: @Strawberry It looks like bad database/table design to me.  I'd like to see each doc type in a separate row, with an ID column to indicate the type.

Comment: @Tim Biegelesen I won't argue that it is possibly a bad design. And would actually appreciate guidance of how to fix the design. What that wold mean is I would have to change my form to perform multiple insert on one submit, so as to submit the 3 or even 4 different document types when applicable. This was my first attempt at such a setup, so can only guess that there may be a number of flaws in my design.

Comment: Are there always two records per `entity_number` group?

Comment: No, the may only be one document to upload. The scenarios differ based on the documents received. At times there may be one document, other times there may be 2, 3, or even as many as 5 different document types to upload.

Comment: @timbiegeleisen agreed!

Comment: I recommend that you redesign your table.  One document, at one point in time, per record.  Someone may give you a workaround but your current approach is going to be tough to work with.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to start looking at the redesign of both the form and the table structure.

Comment: So I have restructured my above table to create a new record for each document type. I have updated my question to indicate these changes.